# How Does Java choose the protocol for ClientHello

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I know different JVMs have different lists of enabled protocols . How does a JVM choose teh protocol version from the list ?

1. Does it choose the highest enabled version ?
2. I read that all protocols are enabled by default for servers ( **unlike** the client which has to choose the enabled protocols by using -Dhttps.protocols switch ) .
   So if a JVM is running with -server switch but makes a client call to another https site, which protocol will be used ? Will it be the highest supported version protocol for that releae of Java ?
3. How exactly does the switch -Djdk.tls.client.protocols differ from the -Dhttp.protocols switch ? ( Both appears to be controlling the list of enabled client side protocols ? ( And neither seems to be affecting the list of protocols supported by teh server )
4. Is there any way to selectively turn off certain protocols for the server ?

--sony

Comment: The `-server` switch doesn't do what you think. As for the TLS implementation, that varies by server (program). Apache Tomcat differs from Jetty, and both differ from Weblogic (to pick three). You need to tell us which server you are using.

Answer (score 3):

> I know different JVMs have different lists of enabled protocols . How does a JVM choose teh protocol version from the list ?
>   1. Does it choose the highest enabled version?

Yes.

> 2. I read that all protocols are enabled by default for servers (**unlike** the client which has to choose the enabled protocols by using -Dhttps.protocols switch).

I don't know where you read that, but all *secure* protocols are enabled by default for both clients and servers. The client *may* but *need not* use `https.protocols`.

> So if a JVM is running with -server switch but makes a client call to another https site, which protocol will be used ? Will it be the highest supported version protocol for that releae of Java ?

Yes. The -server switch is irrelevant to this. It selects an implementation of HotSpot. Nothing to do with TLS whatsoever.

> 3. How exactly does the switch -Djdk.tls.client.protocols differ from the -Dhttp.protocols switch?

The former is for all TLS; the latter for HTTPS only.

> 4. Is there any way to selectively turn off certain protocols for the server?

For which server? It's configurable in Tomcat, and if you're writing the server yourself you can configure the `SSLServerSocket` directly yourself.